# Html tag is not supporting "\n"(new line) in android

Tags: android, html, newline, line-breaks

```
static String test2 = " <h1> THis is the \n test </h1>";
TextView tst;
tst.setText(Html.fromHtml(test2));
```

Output:

## THis is the test

Required Output:

## THis is the 
test

without replacing "\n" to "
" is it possible??

Comment: use `<br>` instead of `\n`?

Answer (score 0):

`\n` will not work in HMTL, you should use `<br>` tag for new line in html

```
static String test2 = " <h1> THis is the <br> test </h1>";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an difference between `\n` and `<br>`.

"`<br>`" is the HTML Tag for a Line break while `\n` is the Unix Tag which will display a line break in the rendered source code but not in the rendered view in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in XML also by putting **\n** in double qoutes

> make string resource

```
<string name="htmltext"><u><i>Project Title</i></u><u>Smart City Apps</u>+"\n"+Developed by Stack.</string>
android:text="@string/htmltext"/>
```